# Is there a way to automatically make the command prompt to answer 'y' when asked if I want to overwrite my local DB?

Tags: python, mysql, bash

I have a script that pulls down the latest copy of our DB. Once it's downloaded, it runs:

```
importCommand = mysql -u {user deets} -h 127.0.0.1 -P 8082 + databaseName + '<' + fileImport
p = subprocess.Popen(importCommand, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

To import the DB. However, when it hits the mysql command there, you always have to confirm:

`/the/path/to/my/downloaded/file.sql already exists -- do you wish to overwrite (y or n)?`.

I frequently pull down new ones, and it would be good to be able to just set this running and leave it to do its job. As it happens, I set it running and then have to confirm the above statement for the import to start.

Is there any way to add a flag to the mysql command there automatically accept yes, a bit like when you do `npm init --y`?

Comment: please, provide the command you use to download the `file.sql`. From the description, i understand that the issue is with sql file that exists.

Comment: try with `--force` maybe?

Comment: Is there a reason that you aren't just using shell in the first place?